# Is it possible to use a graphic menu system and collapse it to the bootstrap responsive menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, menubar

We have a basic 3-column site. The left column consists of large graphic images which serve as the navigation system for the site. Basically a column of buttons. The site is designed with a basic bootstrap 3 framework. I was wondering if it is possible to replace the left column of image-buttons with the horizontal collapsed menu when the browser width falls to mobile size? The buttons just don't look good on mobile platforms and push the main content down too far.

Thanks,
CJ

Comment: Can you provide a link or image to help me better understand? You might be able to add those three buttons to the regular nav and just give them the classes `visible-xs visible-sm` and then give your big buttons the classes `hidden-xs hidden-sm` this way, when when the user is on the full size browser they will see the big buttons but a on mobile browser they would see just the collapse menu.

Comment: I was thinking about the hidden class but wasn't sure if it would still 'reserve' the empty space where the buttons were and cause a large blank area. But here is the development site: http://designedgraphics.net/test.html There's a lot of things that aren't quite right yet, so ignore those. But basically I'd like to get rid of the buttons in the left column and add in a horizontal navbar (collapsed) when viewing on mobile devices.

Comment: basically you would have two `nav` one that is going to have the classes `visible-xs visible-sm` this is going to be the bootstrap collapse menu and your current nav would have the classes `hidden-xs hidden-sm`

Comment: Thanks Robert, that seems to be the way to go. I'll probably just use the xs classes as I think the buttons will work on small tablets.

Comment: I am going to post my comment as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you would have two nav one that is going to have the classes `visible-xs visible-sm` this is going to be the bootstrap collapse menu and your current nav would have the classes `hidden-xs hidden-sm`